# VirtualBox fails with "Implementation of the USB 2.0 controller not found" after upgrading

Tags: virtualbox

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, When I launch my VirtualBox virtual machine I get:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine win7pro32bit.
Implementation of the USB 2.0 controller not found!
Because the USB 2.0 controller state is part of the saved VM state, the VM cannot be
 started. To fix this problem, either install the 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack'
 or disable USB 2.0 support in the VM settings (VERR_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

The solution to the [same question for 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223162/oracle-virtualbox-does-not-open-since-upgrade) does NOT fix the problem:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

UPDATE: Also happens when upgrading VirtualBox itself to 5.0, within existing Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Also happens with USB 3.0 updating 6.1.30 to 6.1.32 — so slipshod.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Download and install `VirtualBox extension pack` from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)(according to your VirtualBox version). It may solve your problem.

Because your error report says like that.

```
To fix this problem, either install the 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack'
```

Comment: I got this error upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 16.10, this fixed it ^^

Comment: You can install it just by double clicking at the downloaded file

Comment: Make sure about the version of the `VirtualBox` installed at the host to install the `Extension Pack`.

Comment: To that, I wonder: if they know the error and the fix, what's holding them back to getting you the link to install it right away?

Answer (score 12):

I tried to install a virtual machine with windows XP and had a similar error.
So i deactivated the USB controller and the machine is working now.

Maybe this will help someone.

start virtualbox -> right click on a machine (the machine should powered off) -> settings and now look on the screenshot
[image]

there you can enable/disable it.

Answer (score -1):

**If you can't start after upgrade, somewhere along the lines of...**

> A possible reason for this error is a missing extension pack. Note that 
>   as of VirtualBox 4.0, certain features...  VERR_PDM_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND

1. Download the *version matching* extension pack (there's only 1 link for the download, fit for all platforms): 
   https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
2. in your download folder (all in one line): 

   `$> sudo VBoxManage extpack install --replace Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-………….vbox-extpack`
3. important, also do: `sudo VBoxManage extpack cleanup`
4. possibly a right-click „discard saved status“ (in case you „hibernated“ open&running VMs)
5. **re-starting your VMs should work now.**(even w/o closing and opening the virtual box application, in my case)

Great advice [found here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-manually-install-the-virtualbox-extension-pack/).

Comment: This is, more or less, the same as the accepted answer from  Apr 23 '14 ...