# Got error during installation of Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, virtualization, root, oracle

I have Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.1.38 installed for long time:

```
$ apt-cache policy virtualbox-5.1 
virtualbox-5.1:
  Installed: 5.1.38-122592~Ubuntu~xenial
  Candidate: 5.1.38-122592~Ubuntu~xenial
  Version table:
 *** 5.1.38-122592~Ubuntu~xenial 500
        500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial/contrib amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I have not ran kernel updates, or something DKMS-related today.

The problem started with "Implementation of the USB 2.0 controller not found!" as in [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/453393/66509).

So I downloaded corresponding version of [Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.38/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack) and tried to install it by clicking on the file in `~/Downloads` folder.

Then VirtualBox opened, suggested me to install extpack:

[image: VirtualBox question]

I clicked Install and accepted license.

Then the following error window was shown:

> [image: VirtualBox - Error]
>
> The installer failed with exit code 127: Error creating textual authentication agent: Error opening current controlling terminal for the process (`/dev/tty'): No such device or address.

Same with console way of installation:

```
$ VBoxManage extpack install ~/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack 
VirtualBox Extension Pack Personal Use and Evaluation License (PUEL)
...
Do you agree to these license terms and conditions (y/n)? y

License accepted. For batch installaltion add
--accept-license=b674970f720eb020ad18926a9268607089cc1703908696d24a04aa870f34c8e8
to the VBoxManage command line.

0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to install "/home/norbert/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack"
VBoxManage: error: The installer failed with exit code 127: Error creating textual authentication agent: Error opening current controlling terminal for the process (`/dev/tty'): No such device or address
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ExtPackManagerWrap, interface IExtPackManager
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleExtPack(HandlerArg*)" at line 1201 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

My user is a member of `vboxusers` group.

What to do with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtualbox Extension Pack needs to be installed using root powers according to these bug reports:

- [Extpack "Error creating textual authentication agent"](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=44367)
- [ExtPack installation failure](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17034)
- [Extpack installation fails](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=84195)

Stack Exchange has the latest [installation instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289685/how-to-install-virtualbox-extension-pack-to-virtualbox-latest-version-on-linux)

```
LatestVirtualBoxVersion=$(wget -qO - http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/LATEST.TXT) && wget "http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/${LatestVirtualBoxVersion}/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-${LatestVirtualBoxVersion}.vbox-extpack"
https://www.virtualbox.org/download/hashes/${LatestVirtualBoxVersion}/SHA256SUMS
sudo VBoxManage extpack install --replace Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-${LatestVirtualBoxVersion}.vbox-extpack
VBoxManage list extpacks
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was in hurry, so I solved this issue with GUI and terminal ways. But your answer is great because of `LatestVirtualBoxVersion` part.

Comment: Thank you. It was good timed question because I installing VB Ext Pack is on my to-do list. I think this thread can help many people down the road.

Answer (score 3):

Any of the following methods will solve the issue:

## * GUI way

1. Run VirtualBox as root

   ```
    sudo virtualbox
   ```
2. Go to **File→Preferences** (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)
3. Open **Extensions** tab
4. Click top right button [image: Add new package] labeled with *Add new package*.
5. Select downloaded extpack, click Install, agree with license
6. Close VirtualBox

Then open VirtualBox as normal user and repeat steps 2-5 again.

## * Terminal way

Install with `VBoxManage` command:

```
$ sudo VBoxManage extpack install \
~/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack 
...
Successfully installed "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack".
```

---

As the result it is shown in **Preferences→Extensions**:

[image: ExtPack installed]

and in terminal:

```
$ vboxmanage list extpacks
Extension Packs: 1
Pack no. 0:   Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack
Version:      5.1.38
Revision:     122592
Edition:      
Description:  USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 Host Controller, Host Webcam, VirtualBox RDP, PXE ROM, Disk Encryption, NVMe.
VRDE Module:  VBoxVRDP
Usable:       true 
Why unusable:
```