# Ubuntu on Virtual Machine is not booting

Tags: 14.04, boot, 18.04, virtualbox

I just set up a new virtual machine. The host machine is running on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. I installed 18.04 on the guest machine. I'm using virtual-box 4.3.36. The first time booting the guest machine worked just normal. In that session I did very few things:

1. `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential` as suggested to be by @N0rbert in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084881/shared-clipboard-is-not-working-and-cant-use-sudo-commands-on-host-machine/1085237?noredirect=1#comment1784763_1085237) question, that I asked before about a different Problem
2. Install guest-additions
3. Reboot machine

Now after this reboot, unfortunately nothing happened. Instead the following blackwindow appeared:
[image: Ubuntu doesn't boot, and nothing happens]
So I tried fixing it, by using a [Boot-Repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/), which didn't change a thing. So afterwards my next step was to try to fix it, using the suggestions in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371432/how-to-troubleshoot-booting-to-a-black-screen-on-virtualbox/692746) question. Here the Problem is, that I just can't do what the answerer suggests there. First I can't install a new virtual box version, because I'm not admin on the host machine. Second: When I press Host+F1 in guest machine, nothing happens.
Can anyone suggest any other fixes? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Btw the only reason I even set up a new virtual machine was because the one that I already had set up was not working anymore. I'm using different host-machines every day (and I can't change that unfotunately) and the machine that I had set up on the one day didn't work on the other day. So I thought it's because of the host machine and I installed a new guest machine which then turned out to not be working, either.

EDIT 2: Great, rerunning boot-repair is not an option anymore either. Trying to rerun it prompts me the language selection and after that results in this screen:
[image]

EDIT 3: As requested [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wxdjBnQpHN/)'s the link to the output of boot-repair.

Comment: @Melebius What do you mean? Boot-Repair-disk is a link in my question to where I got Boot-Repair from.

Comment: When you run Boot-Repair, it shall upload your computer details and provide a URL to share it, unless you opted out. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Recommended_repair and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info for details.

Comment: @Melebius Well, I didn't opt that out, but unfortunately I didn't save the link either :D So give me a minute, I'll run boot-repair again.

Comment: @Melebius Unfortunately I can't run boot-repair again anymore. I just tried to and it resulted in the screen, that I added to the question. Is there any other way I can still obtain the correct link of my first boot-repair run?

Comment: The [corrupted graphics](https://askubuntu.com/a/868362/250300) could be solved by switching to a virtual console and back.

Comment: @Melebius Nope, doesn't work. If I press CTRL + ALT + F2, it kills the session on my host machine instead of the guest machine, even though I used left-ctrl while the host key is right-ctrl

Comment: In your case (Linux guest on Linux host), you have to use the Host key instead of Ctrl+Alt, see my updated answer or [another answer to the same question](https://askubuntu.com/a/918485/250300).

Comment: @Melebius Thanks, that worked. Find the link in the edited question